# How Much Distance is Covered by Each "Unit" of Longitude and Latitude?

Tags: probability, geometry, trigonometry, circles

The coordinates of the Eiffel Tower are (Longitude: 48.8584° N, Latitude: 2.2945° E). I am interested in randomly generating 100 points that are located within a 12 KM radius of the Eiffel Tower. In other words, I would like to randomly generate 100 pairs of (Longitude, Latitude) that are located within a 12 KM radius of the Eiffel Tower.

According to this question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-and-km-distance), the following formulas can be used to convert Longitude and Latitude to KM:

- Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km
- Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km

Thus, if I want to find out a 12 KM radius, the corresponding maximum ranges should be:

- Max Latitude Range: 12 * (1/110.574) = 0.1085246
- Max Longitude Range: 111.320*cos(0.1085246) = 110.6651 -> 1/110.6651 = 0.009036273

Using this information, I tried to simulate points and plot them (in the R programming language):

```
library(leaflet)
# for some reason, you have to call "long" as "lat" and vice versa - otherwise the points appear in the wrong locations all together 
id = 1:100
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 100, 0.1085246 , 1)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 100, 0.009036273 , 1)

my_data = data.frame(id, lat, long)

library(leaflet)
my_data %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
```

But these points do not appear near the Eiffel Tower - some of them are even in Belgium! :

[image]

I reduced the variance and now the points appear closer:

```
# reduce variance
id = 1:100
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 100, 0.1085246 , 0.01)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 100, 0.009036273 , 0.01)

my_data = data.frame(id, lat, long)

my_data %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
```

[image]

But this of course required some guess work and playing around - ideally, I would like a more "mathematical approach".

- **Is there some standard formula I can use to make sure that no matter what initial coordinate I choose (e.g. Eiffel Tower, Statue of Liberty, etc.), the randomly generated points will always fall in a certain radius?**

Thank you!

Comment: You have longitude and latitude backwards in your coordinates.  The Eiffel tower is close to Greenwich in the East-West direction, which is $0$ degrees so its longitude is 2.3 degrees.  You do not explain what we should look at on the maps.  Presumably the circle labeled 41 contains 41 points as the numbers plus the three blue dots add to 100.  We don't have a clue what rnorm is supposed to do, but I am sure it is not doing what you think.  Why not print out the coordinates you get, put them in a spreadsheet, and graph the results?

Comment: You don't have a formula problem as you understand the size of a degree in each direction.  This is debugging, not math.

Comment: Longitude lines get closer together, as one travels from the equator to either the (due) north or south pole.  Therefore, any formula that you derive, will, with respective to the distance between longitude lines, only be pertinent for a specific latitude.  You have to re-compute the distance between longitude lines, for each latitude.  Alternatively, you could strive for a general formula for the distance between longitude lines, as a function of latitude.

Comment: @user2661923:  OP has that with the cos(latitude) term in the distance for one degree of longitude

Comment: Using a variance of $1$ means that your $\pm 1\sigma$ range is about $(-.9,1.1)$ so it is not surprising they are far away from the tower.  For debugging you should use a uniform distribution so you know better what to expect.  The variance should be the square of the number of degrees that represents $12$ km or about $0.01$  Another more important question is why all your points wind up on top of each other.

Comment: @RossMillikan good point; missed that.

Comment: @antonyaro8;  Did you consider concentric circles and geodesic polar coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

> The coordinates of the Eiffel Tower are (Longitude: $48.8584^\circ$ N, Latitude: $2.2945^\circ$ E)

You seem to have a misconception of what *latitude* and *longitude* mean.
The coordinate $48.8584^\circ$ N is the **latitude** of the Eiffel Tower, not its longitude.
The coordinate $2.2945^\circ$ E is the **longitude** of the Eiffel Tower, not its latitude.

> Max Latitude Range: $12 \times (1/110.574) = 0.1085246$

This is correct.

> Max Longitude Range: $111.320\times\cos(0.1085246) = 110.6651 \rightarrow 1/110.6651 = 0.009036273$

There are multiple errors here. First, the "latitude" in the formula
$111.320 \cos(\mathrm{latitude})$ should literally be the latitude of the Eiffel Tower, $48.8584^\circ,$ not the "latitude range" of your random location.
So you should have
$111.320\times\cos(48.8584^\circ) \approx 111.320\times 0.657922 \approx 73.2399.$
Second, the reciprocal of this number gives you the number of degrees per kilometer,
but you have forgotten to multiply by $12$ to get the number of degrees in $12$ km.

In general, except near the equator, you should have a larger range of longitudes within one kilometer than the range of latitudes within one kilometer.
You should also be aware that that the method you are attempting to use here is not good near the north or south pole.

> ```
> # for some reason, you have to call "long" as "lat" and vice versa
> ```

The reason is that what you call "latitude" actually is longitude and vice versa.
The software library uses the correct definitions, while yours are mistakenly swapped.

> ```
> long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 100, 0.1085246 , 1)
> lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 100, 0.009036273 , 1)
> ```

Presumably, to have a set of points in a disk centered at the latitude and longitude of the Eiffel Tower, you want the mean longitude to be the same as the longitude of the tower. But the expression `rnorm( 100, 0.1085246 , 1)` gives you $100$ values distributed with a mean of $0.1085246$; when you add $2.2945$ to this, you get a random distribution with a mean of $2.2945 + 0.1085246$, so the center of your random distribution of points is several kilometers to the east of the tower.
Moreover, the last parameter is the standard deviation of the distribution;
`rnorm( 100, 0.1085246 , 1)` gives you a standard deviation of $1$.
Since $1$ degree of latitude is more than $110$ km and $1$ degree of longitude (near the Eiffel Tower) is more than $73$ km, a point at one standard deviation away from the mean (in either latitude or longitude) will be much further away than desired.
Moreover, keep in mind that the standard deviation of the normal distribution is just the bounds within which *some* of the points will land. For a bivariate normal distribution $(X,Y)$ with no correlation and equal variance in both variables,
fewer than $40\%$ of points will fall within the disk $X^2 + Y^2 \leq 1,$
which for you corresponds to an ellipse of semimajor axis $110$ km and semiminor axis $73$ km centered several km to the east (and slightly north) of the Eiffel Tower.
Most of the points in a random distribution will fall *outside* that ellipse.

> ```
> long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 100, 0.1085246 , 0.01)
> lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 100, 0.009036273 , 0.01)
> ```

Now you've reduced the standard deviation to $0.01$, so the points aren't scattered so far from the center of the distribution, but we still have no connection to the desired $12$ km radius and the center of the distribution is still several kilometers away from the Eiffel Tower, as evidenced by your picture of your results (annotated below).

[image]

Based on your assertion that you want all $100$ of your points to be within
$12$ km of the Eiffel Tower, that immediately suggests that you want a distribution with a finite range of values, not one with an infinite range of values like a normal distribution.
Secondly, when you say a radius of $12$ km, you are saying you want the points to be within a circle of radius $12$ km, not within a square that extends $12$ km north and south and $12$ km east and west of the Eiffel Tower,
and (presumably) not all in a square inscribed in the circle of radius $12$ km.
This implies that you don't want latitude and longitude to be independent random variables.
Therefore the entire idea of using one random variable to set `lat` and another random variable to set `long` will never give the results you said you want.

I suggest that instead of latitude and longitude, you consider the distance and direction from the Eiffel Tower.
Measuring all distances in kilometers, the distance $r$ of random point uniformly distributed within a circle of radius $12$ follows a triangular distribution with probability density

$$ f_r(r) = \begin{cases}
 \dfrac1{72} r & 0 \leq r \leq 12, \\
 0 & \text{all other $r$.}
\end{cases} $$

The direction $\psi$ can be uniformly distributed over any range of numbers that covers the entire circle once, for example $0$ to $360$ (if you measure the direction in degrees) or $0$ to $2\pi$ (if you measure the direction in radians).

Use these distributions to determine a sequence of $100$ distances $r$ and a sequence of $100$ directions $\psi$. Then you simply need to convert each distance and direction to the latitude and longitude of a point at that distance and direction from the point at $48.8584^\circ$ N, $2.2945^\circ$ E.
There is a function `destPoint` in the `geosphere` library in R that can do this, but you may have to do some manipulations in R to apply it to this set of data.
For these R-specific manipulations you might want to look at the GIS stackexchange, for example [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/336347).

Comment: OP should pay you for debugging work this thorough.